# How to associate additional field with File in FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my web application i'm sending `FormData` from an Angular front-end to a Spring Boot server.

I have the following `Attachment` model:

```
export interface Attachment {
    file: File;
    comment: string;
}
```

I would like to send multiple attachments through one `FormData`.

Currently i can send the files successfully with the following code:

```
attachments: Attachment[] = [];

// pushing some data to the array

const data = new FormData();
for (const attachment of this.attachments) {
      data.append('attachments', attachment.file);
}

// POSTing data to the server
```

But this doesn't include the comments along with the files.

I would like to include the comments as well in a way that the server could identify exactly which comment belongs to which file.

I cannot simply do something like `data.append('attachments', attachment)`, because `FormData` can only have string and `Blob` values.

The best idea i could come up with is to add the comments to the `FormData` with the file names as the keys:

```
for (const attachment of this.attachments) {
      data.append('attachments', attachment.file);

      // the key is the file name and the value is the comment
      data.append(attachment.file.name, attachment.comment);
}
```

But this doesn't seem like a good solution and it's cumbersome to parse on the backend as well.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: formdata can hold key-value pairs and its perfectly fine to send multipart form content alongwith your regular string key-value pairs.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee My problem is not sending multipart content along with regular key-value pairs but sending them in a way that the server can unambiguously identify the file-comment pairs.

Comment: @justanoob assuming filename is unique, maybe you could `data.append(\`${attachment.file.name}@file\`, attachment.file)` and `data.append(\`${attachment.file.name}@comment\`, attachment.comment)`. Server-side you can easy rebuild a better structure to match comment and file that starts with the same name.

Comment: You can also stringify your JSON and parse it on server:
`data.append('attachment', JSON.stringify(attachment))`

Comment: @justanoob I know this thread is old, but were you able to figure out a solution for this? I'm in the same predicament.